# Is there better way to subtract of sum fields without summing again in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say Point table looks like this,

```
point_table
- id (pk)
- amount (Integer)
- used_amount (Integer)
```

And I write sql like below

```
SELECT
     SUM(amount) as amount,
     SUM(used_amount) as used,
     SUM(amount) - SUM(used_amount) as unused,
FROM point_table
```

It works well. But I'm not sure it's a best way to get subtraction of summed fields.
I think it calculate unnecessary summing again.

Is there any better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: "I think it calculate unnecessary summing again." -- It most likely doesn't. Or do you have a plan indication so? Then share it please.

Comment: oh, although I said it, I'm not sure it execute summing again. I don't have much experience with sql. May I ask where to find the document about kind of caching calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that:

```
SELECT
     amount, used, amount-used AS unused
FROM (
SELECT
     SUM(amount) as amount,
     SUM(used_amount) as used
FROM point_table)
```

or:

```
SELECT
     SUM(amount) as amount,
     SUM(used_amount) as used,
     SUM(amount - used_amount) as unused,
FROM point_table
```